# Search pattern and select particular pattern from text

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have text like this "`running hl loan hdfc 9.5% customer is not interested`"
I want to select only `9.5%` from entire string. Whatever string would be, but I want select only % value.

Comment: Check if DB engine that You are using supports regular expressions. For example - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp , https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html ...

Comment: Tag the DBMS product which are you using (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server ... etc.). "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: So if column value is `10% 9.5% 100%` what is result you desire to see ?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL-Server you can use [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql), [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) and [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql):

```
declare @str as varchar(155)
set @str = 'running hl loan hdfc 8569.5% customer is not interested'

select SUBSTRING(@str, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @str), CHARINDEX('%', @str) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @str) + 1)
```